# VS Code ASP.NET MVC System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using VS Code 2019 on a Mac and when running my program (I've only added one model, one controller and one view as per a tutorial) I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.TypeLoadException
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'
```

It's showing up in the Startup.cs file at the bottom under app.useEndpoints:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace vidlytest
{
   public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }



    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: the program would not find the mentioned DLL. See if the version is correct everywhere and also check if Dll is available in bin.

Comment: This is startup code for ASP.NET Core. System.Web relies on mscorlib which won't load in .NET Core. You've taken a dependency on something that's designed for use with .NET Framework rather than something compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: I dont see any error in your start file ,did you try updating and re-opening in vs code again